# Mapping in Python for input

Tags: python, python-2.7

For given input:

```
x = [('a',11),('a',12),('b',13),('b',14)]
```

How do i write map function to get output :

```
x_map = {'a':[11,12], 'b':[13,14]}
```

Comment: Use a defaultdict of lists and iteratively append. Have you tried anything? Note that next to nobody recommends the use of python2.7 anymore.

Comment: I am python newbie, I tried doing that with double for loop. For some reason I couldn't get reduce logic right!.

Comment: [edit] your question with your code so we can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I got the thing working with double for loop, I wanted to do the with map and reduce.But the code i wrote is laughable :P so i didnt post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = [('a',11),('a',12),('b',13),('b',14)]
d ={}
for i in x:
    if i[0] not in d:
        d[i[0]] = [i[1]]
    else:
        d[i[0]].append(i[1])
print d
```

output:

```
{'a': [11, 12], 'b': [13, 14]}
```

I think this is what you are looking for

solution 2:

```
x = [('a',11),('a',12),('b',13),('b',14)]
d={}
map(lambda a: d.setdefault(a[0], []).append(a[1]),x)
print d
```

output:

```
{'a': [11, 12], 'b': [13, 14]}
```

Comment: This is efficient to the one i tried! thanks!! But can you please write the snippet using 'lambda map and reduce'

Comment: Hey, Karthik I updated, can you check it once.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is with the help of [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```py
from collections import defaultdict

x = [('a',11),('a',12),('b',13),('b',14)]
x_map = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in x:
    x_map[k].append(v)

# {'a': [11, 12], 'b': [13, 14]}
print dict(x_map)
```